# Создание простого приложения

Tags: c#, silverlight

Здравствуйте! Что необходимо изучить в C# для того, чтобы написать небольшое, несложное приложение на Silverlight? Хорошо бы пример такого приложения. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Silverlight смотри инфу на msdn

Comment: Да они там с каких-то сложных сразу начинают. Ладно пороюсь, может что найду.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Особой специфики в C#, касаемой Silverlight, нет. Начать стоит с "[Hello, World](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/silverlight/22642/)" (еще [заметка](http://silverlighter.ru/blogs/silverlighter_blog/archive/2008/09/30/silverlight-1-quot-hello-world-quot-silverlight-2-vs-2008.aspx)).

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку. У меня правда VS2010 и Silverlight 4. Ладно буду разбираться.